# Issues installing eb cli, ZipImportError

Tags: python, macos, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am following the instructions for installing eb-cli on the github page, https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup and cannot resolve an issue with the zlib library. This is a common issue, but none of the solutions seem to work.  I already have zlib installed on my system (v 1.2.11), but recieve the following error when I run the installer

```
  File "/private/var/folders/9q/pbz7vbms0rv0c4dlsxj0z6h40000gn/T/python-build.20200825221805.35623/Python-3.7.2/Lib/ensurepip/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(ensurepip._main())
  File "/private/var/folders/9q/pbz7vbms0rv0c4dlsxj0z6h40000gn/T/python-build.20200825221805.35623/Python-3.7.2/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 204, in _main
    default_pip=args.default_pip,
  File "/private/var/folders/9q/pbz7vbms0rv0c4dlsxj0z6h40000gn/T/python-build.20200825221805.35623/Python-3.7.2/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 117, in _bootstrap
    return _run_pip(args + [p[0] for p in _PROJECTS], additional_paths)
  File "/private/var/folders/9q/pbz7vbms0rv0c4dlsxj0z6h40000gn/T/python-build.20200825221805.35623/Python-3.7.2/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 27, in _run_pip
    import pip._internal
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
make: *** [install] Error 1
   Exiting due to failure
```

I am on macOS 10.14.6.

Comment: Have you tried the following [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup/issues/76#issuecomment-665627084)? Also if you aren't going tot specify what you've actually tried, its difficult to speculate what may work, what not.

Comment: That fixed the issue. Thanks !

Comment: Glad to hear. If you don't mind I will provide an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments.

The solution was to install `pyenv` using `brew` as shown in this GitHub [post](https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup/issues/76#issuecomment-665627084):

```
brew install pyenv
pyenv install 3.7.2
```